# create and initialize python list

Tags: python, list, file-io

I am stuck on making list using python.

I want to make m x n files such as file00.txt, file01.txt, ..., and file99.txt, but when I tried to make it, it shows some errors. Please let me help out.

```
filename = []

for i in range(0, sm):
    filename.append('') 
    for j in range(0, sn):
        filename[i].append('')
```

Thanks.

Comment: What errors? What is `sm`? What about `sn`?

Comment: sm and sn is just the numbers of rows and coloums.

Comment: @user1399394: What should happen if m and n are larger than 10? Row 11 column 2 would be file112, but so would row 1, column 12...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
filenames = []

for i in range(0, sm):
    row = [] 
    for j in range(0, sn):
        row.append('') # I assume you want to do something more here
    filenames.append(row)
```

Comment: Of course, the much better option is to use a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) for speed and clarity. E.g: `filenames = [['' for j in range(0, sn)] for i in range(0, sm)]`.

Comment: @Lattyware: Yeah, you can use a list comprehension if you can assume that the "something more" is a one-liner. Given the example in the question, it probably is. But if all he wants is empty strings then it could be done even simpler: `[[''] * sn for i in range(0, sm)]`

Answer (score 1):

after i is set to 0 you append an empyty string as filename[0]. in the second for loop in the line

```
    filename[i].append('')
```

this means you actually call

```
    ''.append('')
```

So your error should be:

```
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Hint: Post the error text when asking questions, try to figure out what the error text says about the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = []
for i in range(100):
    filenames.append((str(i) if len(str(i)) > 1 else str(0) + str(i)) + ".txt")
```

At the end you will have file00.txt, file01.txt, ..., and file99.txt in your `filenames` list.

```
filenames_mxn = []
for i in range(m):
    filenames_i = []
    for j in range(n):
        filenames_i.append(filenames[i*n + j])
    filenames_mxn.append(filenames_i)
```

Now you've your files stored in a `m x n` matrix.

Answer (score 0):

multidimensional lists of the items of the same kind are a bit meaningless.
try simple plain list, it's easy to make and easy to use:

```
>>> filenames = ['file' + i + j + '.txt' for i in '0123456789' for j in '0123456789']
>>> filenames
['file00.txt', 'file01.txt', 'file02.txt', ..skipped.. 'file97.txt', 'file98.txt', 'file99.txt']
```